# Render FlatList footer at bottom if list doesn't extend off page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement a bit of a wonky feature here on our `FlatList`. What we want, is if the `FlatList` extends off the page, the footer should behave as normal - i.e. be off screen until the user scrolls enough to reveal it.

However, if there's only a few items, and the `FlatList` does not extend past the page bottom, I want my footer to display on the bottom, rather than right after the list. I've attempted to draw some ASCII art to show better what I mean:

Wrong:

```
---------------
| cell1        |
|--------------|
| cell2        |
|--------------|
| footer       |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

What I'd like:

```
---------------
| cell1        |
|--------------|
| cell2        |
|--------------|
|              |
|              |
|              |
| footer       |
----------------
```

Anyone know how to do this? The important part is that if you need to scroll to see a cell, that the footer does not sit over the list, but still remains after all the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone finds this later and is looking for an answer, here is how I got it to work:

```
<ScrollView 
  style={styles.flatListSectionLayout} 
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 
}}>
  <FlatList
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    ...
  />
  <Footer />
</ScrollView>
```

This will force the `ScrollView`'s content container to grow to fill all available space (`contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}`), and will then force the `FlatList` to take up as much as the remaining space as possible (the `flex: 1` in the `FlatList` style prop.)

Comment: Never put `FlatList` into `ScrollView` because in this case `FlatList` will render all items in one time, so rendering will be slow and memory consumption - high. It's the same as you render items using `.map()` method.
I've explained how to deal with this issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828675/render-flatlist-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-list-even-if-content-is-not-enough/

Comment: This is quite bad actually in-terms of performance / general code readability. Never put a Flatlist inside a scrollview or basically just a scroll view inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today, but I use a better solution.

The solution implemented with `scrollEnabled={false}` will not perform well with more items cause FlatList needs to calculate all child height.

Wen should SomeThing like this:

```js
<FlatList
  ...
  ListFooterComponentStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
/>
```

I put in expo snack for you guys test: https://snack.expo.io/@victorwads/flatlist-with-grow-footer

You can put more items on snack to test more items behavior:

```js
<FlatList
   data={['', '', '' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'']}
   ...
/>
```