# Render FlatList footer at the bottom of the list even if content is not enough

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to render `FlatList`'s footer at the bottom of the page even if there is not enough content to fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to take a look at react-native sources.
[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L899) there is a code which shows adding footer internally.
As you can see it wraps into additional `View` which can be styled using `ListFooterComponentStyle` prop. It's not described for some reason in docs.

So here is the solution:

```
 <FlatList
      data={someData}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
      ListFooterComponentStyle={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}
      ListFooterComponent={<Footer/>}
 ...
 />
```

**UPD:** Update answer using AtlasRider's comment.

Comment: I had to add `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}` to get this to work. I think this is because the underlying ScrollView won't extend down to fill the screen.